# iteration E3 | The action 'destroy' could not be found for CartsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hello All

I'm studying agile web development with rails 4 currently.

here's what I do to clean the cart (iteration E3).

1.to add a button_to in views/cart/show.html.erb

```
<%= button_to 'Empty cart', @cart, method: :delete,
data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

2.to add method destroy in controllers/carts_controller.rb

```
def destroy
  @cart.destroy if @cart.id == session[:cart_id]
  session[:cart_id] = nil
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to store_url, notice: 'Your cart is currently empty' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

3.When i click on Empty cart button, I got this error message "The action 'destroy' could not be found for CartsController", I have checked these code for a lot times.
 I was wondering if there are something wrong else. 
Would you please tell me how to fix this?

routes.rb

```
Depot::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :line_items
  resources :carts
  get "store/index"
  resources :products
  root 'store#index', as: 'store'
end
```

5 errors from rake test, i think it's related, but i don't know how.

```
1) Error:
CartsControllerTest#test_should_create_cart:
AbstractController::ActionNotFound: The action 'create' could not be found for CartsController
    test/controllers/carts_controller_test.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in <class:CartsControllerTest>'
    test/controllers/carts_controller_test.rb:20:in `block in <class:CartsControllerTest>'

  2) Error:
CartsControllerTest#test_should_destroy_cart:
AbstractController::ActionNotFound: The action 'destroy' could not be found for CartsController
    test/controllers/carts_controller_test.rb:45:in `block (2 levels) in <class:CartsControllerTest>'
    test/controllers/carts_controller_test.rb:43:in `block in <class:CartsControllerTest>'

  3) Error:
CartsControllerTest#test_should_get_index:
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
    app/views/carts/index.html.erb:13:in `_app_views_carts_index_html_erb__860143545109165463_70364136402640'
    test/controllers/carts_controller_test.rb:9:in `block in <class:CartsControllerTest>'

  4) Error:
CartsControllerTest#test_should_get_new:
ActionView::Template::Error: First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
    app/views/carts/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_carts__form_html_erb___571452078619530506_70364136338580'
    app/views/carts/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_carts_new_html_erb__717241531793059964_70364164357880'
    test/controllers/carts_controller_test.rb:15:in `block in <class:CartsControllerTest>'

  5) Error:
CartsControllerTest#test_should_update_cart:
AbstractController::ActionNotFound: The action 'update' could not be found for CartsController
    test/controllers/carts_controller_test.rb:38:in `block in <class:CartsControllerTest>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

> ```
>  <%= button_to "Empty cart", {:controller => "carts",:action =>
> 'destroy', :id => cart.id }, :method => :delete %>
> ```

Change your the view folder name to carts.

Comment: i tried this 
<%= button_to 'Empty cart', "carts",:action => 'destroy', :id => cart.id , :method =>:delete,data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
and i have another error message.

Comment: send me your route what you have used for carts

Comment: Depot::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :line_items
  resources :carts
  get "store/index"
  resources :products
  root 'store#index', as: 'store'
end

Answer (score 0):

Check:

- name of instance `@cart` in your `CartsController#show`.
- `resources :carts or resource :cart`, in your `config/routes.rb`

Comment: def show end,it has nothing in side. does it has anything to do with show since i want to empty my cart?

Comment: ok, are you sure that @cart is not nil? do you have an variable instance of this?! Check the server output of  **puts @cart**

Comment: would you please tell me how to do this?

Comment: ok, in your **views/cart/show.html.erb**, before  button_to line, put this line **<%= puts "========#{@cart.inspect}" %>**, then go to server output and look up this.

Comment: it didn't show anything not even ========. is that normal?

Comment: it isn't normal, do you have  **views/cart/** or **views/carts/** ?

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved this problem after a long while checking it out.

If you have this code at the beginning of the carts controller:

private

```
def invalid_cart

   logger.error "Attempt to access invalid cart #{params[:id]}"

   redirect_to store_url, notice: 'Invalid cart'

  end
```

Just delete the word private, and move that method down to the place where you have the methods "set_cart" and "cart_params".

It worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I also had the same error and I found that I have given the singular controller name in my routes instead of plural - I have given `delete 'account/Destroy'` instead of `delete 'accounts/Destroy'`

I know that user has himself answered the question but i thought that may someone else find my post useful in his case